# How to set your Android Studio theme?

Tags: android-studio, themes

I am new in android studio and the default theme of mine sets to kinda dark one. How can I set it to other? If there were...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to got to settings File>Settings... under Appearance & Behavior click on Appearance. You can change the Theme here.

Comment: No problem. If you wouldn't mind click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer to mark it as accepted.